# Does a current clamp measure apparent or active current? And is it accurate?

Tags: power-meter

### 1) Apparent or active

Does an current clamp measure apparent or active current?

I am looking at energy consumption metering solutions for a building. So far, the affordable products seem to click clamps on one or more of the phases (and maybe on zero) going into the house.

Or maybe some products measure one, and some measure the other?

### 2) Reliability / precision of clamps

Is a clamp on the outside of a cable really precise? Maybe only the high-end / expensive clamps are precise? Or is this such a simple principle that I can even trust relatively cheap solutions, such as Efergy ([link to installation instruction video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gky4DukEmeg))?

Are non-clamp solutions generally more reliable/precise?

Comment: Or maybe it does not even make sense to talk about "active current", maybe I need to talk about "active power"?

Comment: I assume the apparent/active distinction is related to Power Factor Corrections (PFC). For householders, I expect the most accurate measurement is likely to come from using the optical output of the supply-company meter. Or install your own commercial meter. For industrial settings, no doubt there are better options.

Comment: Current is current. Power can be real average power (what you generally get billed on) or reactive (implying a phase angle between V and I) or apparent (Vrms * I rms). In all cases an ammeter (of any type) does not know the difference. You need a wattmeter to read power and, it uses a current clamp (or measurement) and a voltage measurement to calculate real power.

Answer (score 3):

A clamp-on ammeter has no way of knowing the phase relationship between the current and the voltage, so it only gives a magnitude reading, which I guess is what you're calling "apparent current". It can't mesaure "real power" unless it also has a voltage reference input.

The split core of a good clamp-on meter gives readings that are as accurate as a non-split current transformer. In any case, read the accuracy specifications of the meter you're considering.